# monogdb full text search, ignore characters

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, find

Im implementing a mongodb search.
The search performs a find on field values:

```json
[{
  value: "my.string.here"
}, {
  value: "my other here"
}{
  ...
}]
```

When i enter "my" both entries are found. What have my query to look like to ignore the dots on the first entry? So when i enter "my string" the first element gets returned?

Actually it works only when i enter "my.string" which is not nice.

```js
    let limit = Number(req.query.limit || 100);
    let skip = Number(req.query.skip || 0);

    collection.find({
        $or: [{
            value: new RegExp(req.body.search, "gi")
        }, {
            tags: {
                $in: req.body.search.split(",").map((val) => {
                    return new RegExp(val, "gi")
                })
            }
        }]
    }).skip(skip).limit(limit).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

A solution could look like this:

```js
    let query = {
        $or: [{
            name: new RegExp(req.body.search, "gi")
        }, {
            tags: {
                $in: req.body.search.split(",").map((val) => {
                    return new RegExp(val, "gi")
                })
            }
        }, {
            name: new RegExp(req.body.search.split(' ').join('.'), "gi")
        }, {
            name: new RegExp(req.body.search.split(' ').join('_'), "gi")
        }, {
            name: new RegExp(req.body.search.split(' ').join('-'), "gi")
        }]
    };
```

But i find it ugly and not elegant. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Have you considered a text index?

Comment: I had thought about it but never tried. does it work with the text index ?